# handle child component click in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a multiselect in React. What I have done now is forcing user to have the following properties in the objects that are passed inside an array to my multiselect component.

```
interface IMandatoryPropertyOnUserData {
  id: string | number
  optionText: string | number
  optionValue: any
  checked?: Boolean | undefined
}
```

The `optionText` is the text in the dropdown and `optionValue` is the value behind it. [Antd](https://ant.design/components/select/) has a `Select` with a `Option` component that is passed as `children` to the `Select` component.

This is how my multiselect component is currently used.

```
 <MultiSelect
    dropdownData={[{ id: 1, optionText: 'usa', optionValue: 1, time: 'a' }]}
    onSelect={(selectedValues) => {
      console.log(selectedValues)
    }}
  />
```

Creating options in my component:

```
     const dropdownEl = dropdownData.map((data) => {
        return (
         <div className={optionWrapper} onClick={() => handleOptionSelected(data)}>
           {data.optionText}
         </div>
    )
  })
```

I am trying to avoid making the user pass mandatory props and do it like Antd's select.

This is example of Antd's `select`: https://codesandbox.io/s/hqkmv  There's no `onClick` callback prop on the `Option` component.

I can't figure out how to call and tell the `Select` component when the `Option` component is clicked like Antd.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the user pass only the options values to 'MultiSelect' and then create the options components inside of the MultiSelect component and manage the selection with "onClick" internally.

Comment: I think that's what I have already done, but I don't know what the text inside the dropdown should be. So I am making user pass `{ id: 1, optionText: 'usa', optionValue: 1}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'the text inside the dropdown'. If the user gives you an array of string options, for example ["dog", "cat", "whale", "bird"] than the dropdown will contain these options and inside of the MultiSelect, you can create an option component for each with key and onclick without the need for the user to pass it.